# Instalacion de CodeIgniter 4 en Hosting Compartido

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

Tengo un problema con la instalación y puesta en marcha con CodeIgniter 4 en hosting compartido, exactamente con ionos.

Quiero crear una api con este framework y lo quiero alojar en [https://midominio.es/api/v2/[iria](https://midominio.es/api/v2/%5Biria) aquí].

He subido toda la carpeta a esta ruta en el hosting pero al ejecutar dicha url me salta el error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function run() on int in /homepages/7/d854550294/htdocs/clickandbuilds/midominio/api/v2/public/index.php:39 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /homepages/7/d854550294/htdocs/clickandbuilds/midominio/api/v2/public/index.php on line 39
```

mi .htaccess dentro de la carpeta public de codeigniter es el siguiente

```
# Disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Rewrite engine
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Turning on the rewrite engine is necessary for the following rules and features.
# FollowSymLinks must be enabled for this to work.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # If you installed CodeIgniter in a subfolder, you will need to
    # change the following line to match the subfolder you need.
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase
    # RewriteBase /

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Rewrite "www.example.com -> example.com"
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    # Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    # such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    # request to the front controller, index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([\s\S]*)$ index.php/$1 [L,NC,QSA]

    # Ensure Authorization header is passed along
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>

# Disable server signature start
    ServerSignature Off
# Disable server signature end
```

Mi estrucutura de carpetas es la que viene por defecto.

```
--app
--public
  --.htaccess
--tests
--vendor
--writable
```

¿Alguien puede ayudarme a corregir este error? ¿o alguna guia de instalacion en este entorno?
He seguido los pasos de la web oficial y no lo he conseguido...

Gracias de antemano.
Un saludo.

Comment: Que versión de PHP usa tu hosting?

Comment: Gracias @MRDev es la versión 8.0.

Comment: por lo que veo el `.htaccess` es el predefinido que trae el framework. Si agregaste la dirección en `base_url`?, te muestra algún otro mensaje?

Comment: Gracias @MRDev, al final era la tonteria mas grande del mundo. Abro respuesta con mi arreglo para que funcione.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues al final lo he resuelto. Era la cosa más tonta del mundo. En un principio copié toda la carpeta de CI al raiz de la carpeta de mi dominio, y esto creo que no se hace así. Lo que hice fue copiar la carpeta framework que hay dentro de la carpeta vendor\codeigniter4\ y copiarla en la raiz de la subcarpeta del dominio, en mi caso

```
https://midominio.es/api/v2/
```

Con esto ya funcionaria todo. Por lo menos a mi me ha funcionado.

Gracias de antemano.
Un saludo.